# Inheriting from ApplicationUser returns null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure if it a issue with my class models or RegisterIvestor.cs None of my Investor.cs properties are saved and returning null values.

I'm trying to create different logins for different types of users. I want all users to save to ApplicationUser. I found the code below builds and migrates find just getting null data.

ApplicationDBContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>

{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .HasOne(p => p.Investor)
          .WithOne(b => b.ApplicationUser)
          .HasForeignKey<Investor>(b => b.InvestorForeignKeyID);

    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Investor> Investor { get; set; }
}
```

RegisterInvestor.cshtml.cs

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                LastName = Input.LastName,
                Address = Input.Address,
                City = Input.City,
                State = Input.State,
                Zip = Input.Zip

                Investor = new Investor()
                {
                        SsnTaxId = Input.SsnTaxId,
                        DOB = Input.DOB,
                        DriverClass = Input.DriverClass,
                        LicenseNumber = Input.LicenseNumber                      
                }

            };
        }
        }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Investor  Investor { get; set; }
    //other properties
 }
```

Investor.cs

```
 public class Investor : ApplicationUser
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SSN or TaxID")]
    public string SsnTaxId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }


    public string InvestorForeignKeyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InvestorForeignKeyID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

displaying data

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Investor.SsnTaxId)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't instantiate something with the same name of the class, it's confusing and bad practice:

```
public virtual Investor UserInvestor { get; set; }
```

As for the Invertor being null if you are using a loop in the View there a chance that because you are instantiate the object inside ApplicationUser then they are all null, try something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
   {

        UserInvestor = new Investor();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                LastName = Input.LastName,
                Address = Input.Address,
                City = Input.City,
                State = Input.State,
                Zip = Input.Zip

                UserInvestor.SsnTaxId = Input.SsnTaxId,
                UserInvestor.DOB = Input.DOB,
                UserInvestor.DriverClass = Input.DriverClass,
                UserInvestor.LicenseNumber = Input.LicenseNumber                      
                }

            };
        }
   }
```

Also to display the FirstName in the view do it like this:

```
@Model.FirstName
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Comment: Yeah I get an error UserInvestor does not exist in the current context, Im trying to include the investor properties with applicationuser

Comment: That is correct I believe you have to do this outside the method at the class level.

Comment: Just place this outside "UserInvestor = new Investor();" the method.

Comment: It shows an error, I need to use 'var UserInvestor = new Investor();' but I need to assign the values to 'user' not UserInvestor